# Discord.py adding modifiers to commands

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

So I've seen other bots where you can do a ban command, for example !ban 383777390851260426 -r you crossed the line -t 7d -Nodm

Im curious how you get the modifiers on such as -r.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: what? Can you elaborate?

Comment: so like usually you can do !ban @ user, but on other bots I've seen it where you can do !ban @user and then have additional modifiers like -r for reason -t 7d etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are called arguments or parameter. One way of *parsing* through them is by looking at all the text you got from the method, and look for each *option* or *parameter* you have.

Here is an example of parsing the arguments you get after mentionning the member, feel free to modify this code to connect it with other commands (such as parsing the `time_left` variable into a Datetime, setting a timer for unbanning, etc)

Please note that this code only really uses the reason, and not the time or the -nodm since this require more complex implementation. This is just an example to show you how you could get this started

```
@command()
async def ban(ctx: Context, member: Member, *args):
    reason_index = args.index("-r")  # Returns -1 if not found, else the position of the "-r"
    reason = args[reason_index+1] if reason_index != -1 else None
    time_index = args.index("-t")
    time_left = args[time_index +1] if time_index != -1 else None
    nodm = True if "-Nodm" in args else False
    await member.ban(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(f"I banned {member.mention} with reason {reason} for {time_left}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

```python
@bot.command() #ban command
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def ban(ctx, member:discord.Member=None, *, reason=None): # the * makes that reason argument takes all text even if it has spaces 
    if member == ctx.message.author:
        await ctx.channel.send("You cannot ban yourself")
    if member == None:
        await ctx.channel.send("Who are you going to ban?")
    if reason == None:
        reason = "No reason specified"
    await member.ban(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(f"{member.mention} has been banned because of {reason}")
```

I have no idea if this is not what you ment, also no idea what you ment with -t 7d etc